# How to set accumulated value using for in jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The HTML code is like this:

```html
<ul class="gnb1depth">   <li></li>  <li></li>   <li></li>   <li></li>    </ul>
```

```javascript
$(document).ready(function () {

    var menu_count = $("ul.gnb1depth > li").size()


    for (var a = 0; a < menu_count; a++)
    {

        $("ul.gnb1depth > li").attr("test",a)
    };


});
```

The attribute of li that is set same value to 6(li count is 6).
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setter version of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) which [takes a function as the second argument](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul.gnb1depth > li").attr('test', function (i) {
        return i
    })
});
```

In your case in each iteration of the loop, you are setting the attribute value of all `li` elements instead of targeting the `li` in the specified index.

Comment: this is suit for me. thx Arun! have a nice day from SEOUL, s.KOREA

Answer (score 0):

```
$`("ul.gnb1depth li ").eq(a).attr("test",a)
```

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Just posting a code block without any explanation or context is not good. In its current state your answer might not be of any use to people looking for an answer to this question in the future.

Comment: There is also a typo (the back-tick). Should be: `$("ul.gnb1depth li ").eq(a).attr("test",a);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for`-loop like this:

```
var menu = $("ul.gnb1depth > li");
for (var a = 0; a < menu.length; a++) {
    $(menu[a]).attr("test", a);
};
```

However the vesrion with `attr` method is more jQuery like.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this:

```
$("ul.gnb1depth > li").attr("test",a)
```

to this:

```
$("ul.gnb1depth > li:eq(" + a +")").attr("test",a)
```